# Google maps: Navigate home

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to redirect a user to google maps and show him how to get to NYC from his [home](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1626958?hl=en)(My location definition).

So I been trying this link:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/home/nyc

I expect it to show the user how to get to NYC from his home. But it search places with the name, "home" instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Dr.Molle Because "home" been defined as "my place". You can read more about it in the link that I attached.

Comment: The instructions there didn't work(at least for me, it's not possible to store my home somewhere),  maybe the article is outdated.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, when you edit your question I'll be able to retract it

Comment: @Dr.Molle I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: It's clear now, but it doesn't work for me, also not in classic maps(although my home has been stored there ). However, this feature may be fine for me and you(when it would work), because we would know about the "home". But you can't expect that this is the case for your users(how can you know that they have stored the "home" or are logged in at google). A better approach would be to try to locate the  user via gelocation and when it was  successful create a link(based on the returned LatLng).

Comment: @Dr.Molle There are ways to detect if the user logged in to google. Also I can try to see if the page redirects(May be will work only in application and not a browser) and it's some how related to "home" search or not. So one problem at a time. First lets find a way to make this work for me and for you.

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing I can do to make it work for me. When there is anybody who can fix it he will sit near Mountain View